# Regex to find multiline comments in Python that contain a certain word

Tags: python, regex

How can I define a regex to find multiline comments in python that contain the word "xyz".
Example for a string that should match:

```
"""
blah blah
blah
xyz
blah blah
"""
```

I tried this regex:

`"""((.|\n)(?!"""))*?xyz(.|\n)*?"""`

(grep -i -Pz '"""((.|\n)(?!"""))*?xyz(.|\n)*?"""')

but it was not good enough. for example, for this input

```
 """
    blah blah blah
    blah
"""

   # xyz
               
 def foo(self):
"""
blah
"""
```

it matched this string:

```
"""

   # xyz
               
 def foo(self):
"""
```

The expected behavior in this case it to not match anything since "xyz" is not inside a comment block.

I wanted it to only find "xyz" within opening quotes and closing quotes, but the string it matches is not inside a quotes block. It matches a string that starts with a quote, has "xyz" in it and ends with a quote, but the matched string is NOT inside a python comment block.

Any idea how to get the required behavior from this regex?

Comment: parsing programming languages with regexes is a bad idea mostly. Have you considered the `ast` module?

Comment: @john1994 – Are you really demanding _to get the required behavior from **this** regex?_ How about a quite different approach? And what do you want as output - the whole multiline string, or just the line with "xyz"?

Answer (score 1):

The main challenge is keeping the `"""` ... `"""` balance of *inside* and *outside* a comment.
Here an idea with PCRE (e.g. [PyPI regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) with Python) or `grep -Pz` (like in your example).

```
(?ims)^"""(?:(?:[^"]|"(?!""))*?(xyz))?.*?^"""(?(1)|(*SKIP)(*F))
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tQhvRN/3) (used with `i` *ignorecase*, `m` *multiline* and `s` *dotall* [flags](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refmodifiers.html))

This works because the searchstring is matched [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) to prevent *backtracking* into another match and loosing overall balance. The most simple pattern for keeping the balance would be [`""".*?"""`](https://regex101.com/r/g27voq/1). But as soon as you want to match some substring inside, the regex engine will try to succeed.

To get around this, the searchstring can be matched *optionally* for keeping balance by preventing backtracking. Simplified example: [`"""([^"]*?xyz)?.*?"""`](https://regex101.com/r/C33oOt/1) VS *not wanted* [`"""([^"]*?xyz).*?"""`](https://regex101.com/r/C33oOt/2).

Now to still let the matches without searchstring fail, I used a [conditional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) afterwards together with PCRE verbs [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex). If the *first [group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)* fails (no searchstring inside) the match just gets skipped.

---

For usage with `grep` [here is a demo](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BN1VBXUlJKSYvUaGisiomD8xOQmInw9nqCjUK6UWpBQq6AVX5Cuoa9pm5xZpxQAkNeysgio5Tiq0BshWVlDQ1tew1gNo0Ne31tOwhSjQMNWs0tIK9PQM0NbTcNDXV//8HAA) at tio.run, or alternatively: `pcregrep -M '(?is)pattern'`
As mentioned above in Python this pattern requires *PyPI regex*, see a [Python demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##dVJNT4NAED3LrxjxsoOU2Hhr0nDTGKMx8WjVoCwtSdltlm1spfz2Ort0gVa6EDrz5r352q62eiHF7X6fFyupNCg@5xtISjI8r3GmoHwW50WJHzPfPCye0PtG3vvOeJcGRAxittn@IsZRELdMNsYdC14fH16QBXeIvudpXurPUitKzPyGNxO@d@F/LZMFmE/nNhalHWQ48bFnbKDTknsKhw/pKXQFbSk4Pgcw5RlkUrKSLzOc/K97Lvfo9DSwkKYgCDk0w5aXNkq//aCPnlck@ntBYboaHmW5SHPNFbPXFYLbL/EyqcByn9dF2FiQC@BiXXCVaM4OiUIodaL0dIwTz0xrPyuVC01X9GRllctTww/9PTK5FikkGiqrrEcVF2k9OdBqP6LSZDKnola7RqzEIZH1GIbUVtqCZBuoadmBcyXXK4aIXZNmQgubGjSaSsScs5sQllywnqo0smY4c1rJtDOvYdzGW8Mt4d6woHLk@vwCLKVbwECl4QW46MAieiFrniykDSPu938).

Comment: Wow that looks promising, I gotta say!
But for some reason it does not work when I go "grep -P '(?ms)^"""(?:(?:[^"]|"(?!""))*?(xyz))?.*?^"""(?(1)|(*SKIP)(*F))' test " in the terminal, when test content is exactly like the text you put in the regex testing link.
Am I doing something wrong here? maybe I have to use some other grep flags?

Comment: Yea I understand that, its just weird that the same regex that catches perfectly what I needed in the regex builder link, doesn't do it from the terminal

Comment: @john1994 I tried [this at tio.run](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BN1VBXUlJKSYvUaGisiomD8xOQmInw9nqCjUK6UWpBQq6AVX5Cuoa9pm5xZpxQAkNeysgio5Tiq0BshWVlDQ1tew1gNo0Ne31tOwhSjQMNWs0tIK9PQM0NbTcNDXV//8HAA) which seemd to work well. Another option is to use [`pcregrep`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pcregrep.1.html) (I edited my answer, see last line).